# Create macro that updates fields before save

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and am trying to write a macro that will execute a field update before the user saves the document. My first attempt was going to be intercepting the `Save` command like this:

```
Sub FileSave()
   '
   ' FileSave Macro
   ' Saves the active document or template, and updates fields
   '
    Fields.Update
    ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
```

But one guide recommended not doing that and instead using `DocumentBeforeSave()`, so this is my new attempt:

```
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Fields.Update

End Sub
```

The first example gives me the following error:

> "Runtime error '424': Object required"

The second example doesn't update the fields.  I've tried the second code in both the `ThisDocument` object, and as a new module class. Nevertheless, the fields are still not updating when I save.  On a side note, they work with this.

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
    Fields.Update
    Save
End Sub
```

It seems like a simple task but it just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `ThisDocument` code module, add an `Application` object using the `WithEvents` keyword so that you can respond to its events:

   ```
   Dim WithEvents TheApp As Word.Application
   ```
2. Add an event handler for `Document_Open()` that assigns your variable to the active `Application` object:

   ```
   Private Sub Document_Open()

       Set TheApp = ThisDocument.Application

   End Sub
   ```
3. Add an event handler for `Application_DocumentBeforeSave()`. Within this event use the `Doc` object that's passed to it to update your document:

   ```
   Private Sub TheApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

       Doc.Fields.Update

   End Sub
   ```
4. Save your document as a `"Macro-Enabled Document (*.docm)"`.
5. Close the document and reopen it.

That should be it. If you want to make sure your code is working properly, add a breakpoint or a `MsgBox()` before your `Doc.Fields.Update` statement to make sure the event handler is getting called and check your values before and after the update.